# how to make multiple array value in single array

Tags: php, codeigniter

i got array like follows
specification:

Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => red )

Array ( [0] => 9 [1] => yellow )

Array ( [0] => 9 [1] => red )

i want all [0] index value in one row and all[1] index in next row

option:
Array ( [0] => size [1] => color )

in size all [0] index want to store and in color all[1] want to store

output want to be like follows:

size  [8, 9, 8]

color [red, yellow, red]

```
Source code
<?php

        $where = array(
           'ProductBrand'=>$value->ProductBrand,
           'ProductIsActive'=>1,
           'ProductStatus'=>'Approved'
        );
        $data['id'] = $this->Custom_model->getwhereid('products',$where,array());
```

in this id will get all productid according to brand which was selected

```
        foreach($data['id'] as $key => $row) {
            $where = array(
                'ProductID'=>$row->ProductID,
                'ProductIsActive'=>1,
                'ProductStatus'=>'Approved'
            );
             $jointables = array(
                'categories'=>'CategorySlug=ProductCategory',
                'subcategories'=>'SubCategorySlug=ProductSubCategory',
                'brands'=>'BrandSlug=ProductBrand',
                'producttypes'=>'ProductTypeID=ProductType',
                'optionvalues'=>'OptionValueProductID=ProductID'
            ); 
     $data['spec'] = $this->Custom_model->getwherejoin('products',$jointables,$where,array());

     foreach ($data['spec'] as $key => $spec) {
            $ptoptionname = $spec->ProductTypeOptionName; 
            $ptoptionname = explode (",", $ptoptionname);
            $count=count($ptoptionname);                        
            $specname = $spec->OptionValueSpecification; 
            $specname = explode (",", $specname);
            for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {

            ?>
            <div class="stock-container info-container m-t-20 sizeborder">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div class="stock-box">

                            <span class="label"><?php echo $ptoptionname[$i]; ?> </span>

                        </div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <div class="stock-box"> 

                            <a href=""><span class="productcolor productsizeonclick"> <?php echo $specname[$i]; ?> </span></a>

                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.row -->    
            </div><!-- /.stock-container -->

            <?php } } }?>
```

but my output was follows

size 8

color red

size  9

color yellow

size  9

color red

Comment: Can you format the question to understood your requirement

Comment: did you tried anything? please post a sample of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transpose your `$data` array by calling `array_map()` with a `null` callback and an unpacked `$data` array.

Then you merely use `array_combine()` to apply your desired first level keys.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/VnsE1))

```
$data = [
    ["8","red"],
    ["9", "yellow"],
    ["8","red"]
];

var_export(array_combine(['size', 'color'], array_map(null, ...$data)));
```

Output:

```
array (
  'size' => 
  array (
    0 => '8',
    1 => '9',
    2 => '8',
  ),
  'color' => 
  array (
    0 => 'red',
    1 => 'yellow',
    2 => 'red',
  ),
)
```

The benefit of my technique is that as you add more columns, you never need to add more function calls (this would not be true if calling `array_column()` on each column).  My solution never needs more than two function calls to get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$data=array(
    array("8","red"),
    array("9", "Yellow"),
    array("8","red")
);


$size=[];
$colors=[];

foreach($data as $key=>$value){


echo "<pre>";
print_r($value);

$size[$key]=$value[0];
$colors[$key]=$value[1];

}
print_r($size);
print_r($colors);

# comma seprated

echo "Size List:";
print_r(implode($size, ','));

echo "<br>";

echo "Color List:";
print_r(implode($colors, ','));
?>
```

Comment: Where is the explanation and code tabbing in this answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_column()` function to returns the values from a single column in the input array. After that you can use `implode()` to convert array to string.

```
$data = [ 
  [0 => 8, 1 => 'red'],

  [0 => 9, 1 => 'yellow'],

  [0 => 9, 1 => 'red']
];

$newArray['size'] = array_column($data, 0);
$newArray['color'] = array_column($data, 1);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArray);
echo "</pre>";

echo "<p>Size: " . implode($newArray['size'], ',') . "</p>";
echo "<p>Color: " . implode($newArray['color'], ',') . "</p>";
```